# Non-Pythagorean coins (Part 1)

Tags: mathematics, combinatorics, frobenius

To make payments, the Non-Pythagoreans use coins in three denominations of 999, 1000, and 1001 Oboloi. What is the largest integer amount of Oboloi that can **not** be represented by using these three types of coins?

Comment 1: valid representations use non-negative numbers of coins

Comment 2: [Pythagorean coins](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/9443/pythagorean-coins)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the answer is

> 498500
>  because $498500=498\times999+998$ and in modular arithmetic we have $1000\equiv1\pmod{999}$ and $1001\equiv2\pmod{999}$, so the remainder of $998$ cannot be made by fewer than $499$ additions of positive numbers less than or equal to $2$.

Answer (score 8):

This problem is an instance of the [Frobenius coin problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem).  In fact, the coin values form an arithmetic sequence, whose Frobenius number has the [special form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem#Arithmetic_sequences):

$$
g(a, a+d, \ldots, a+sd) = \left(\left\lfloor\frac{a-2}{s}\right\rfloor+1\right)a + (d-1)(a-1)-1
$$

Here we have:

$$
\begin{align}
g(999, 1000, 1001) &= \\ g(999, 999+1, 999+2\times 1) &= \left(\left\lfloor\frac{999-2}{2}\right\rfloor+1\right)999 + (1-1)(999-1)-1 \\ &= 498\ 500
\end{align}
$$

Thus the largest denomination that cannot be made with the Non-Pythagorean coins is $498\ 500$.

Comment: With a name like "Frobenius," you'd expect the coins to be denominated in Zorkmids, not Oboloi...

Answer (score 2):

The amounts can be written as 999$x$ + 1000$y$ + 1001$z$. If we want to add 1 to it:

- We can increase $y$ and decrease $x$ by 1.
- We can increase $z$ and decrease $y$ by 1.
- If neither can be done ($x$ and $y$ = 0), we can increase $x$ by 500 and decrease $z$ by 499 at the very least.

So, 1001*498=498498 can't rise to 498499 and any amount starting from 499499 can be obtained. Taking 499499 and decreasing $z$s in return for $y$s (the opposite of the second scenario), we can decrement the amount by 1 every time (until 499000). Later, we decrement those new $y$s in return for $x$es (the opposite of the first scenario) until we get to 498501, which is obtainable. By this logic, 498500 is the greatest unobtainable amount.